# How to modify GORM DB pointer in function?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a REST API application written in Go, which uses GORM as ORM. During refactoring of some parts, I wanted to move some common operations to an external function `ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB)`, which takes a pointer to the DB query and modifies it, so that the modified query can be used later.

Example usage:

```
query = shared.DB.Debug()
req.ApplytoDBQuery(query)
if query.find(&data).Error != nil {...}

func (this *MyCustomRequest) ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB) {
    query.Limit(...)
    query.Offset(...)
    query.Where(...)
}
```

I thought, that since I'm passing a pointer to the function, the original query should've been modified, but nothing really happened to the original query.

I've also tried passing a pointer to pointer `ApplyToDBQuery(query **gorm.DB)`, returning the modified pointer `ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB` and out of lack of ideas, even a combination of these two - `ApplyToDBQuery(query **gorm.DB) *gorm.DB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gorm object clone itself for every operation, therefore the original pointed value is never changed.

You should return the latest version of gorm.DB:

```
return query.Limit(...).Offset(...).Where(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method receiver to

```
func (this *MyCustomRequest) ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return query.Limit(...).
        Offset(...).
        Where(...)
}
```

then use it as:

```
query = req.ApplytoDBQuery(query)
if query.find(&data).Error != nil {...}
```

The reason is already pointed by @R3v4n

Answer (score 1):

You should go with what the previous two answers recommend, but, if for some reason, you have to *apply* changes to the passed in pointer, you can still do it "manually".

```
query = shared.DB.Debug()
req.ApplytoDBQuery(query)
if query.find(&data).Error != nil {...}

func (r *MyCustomRequest) ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB) {
    q := query.Limit(...).Offset(...).Where(...)
    *query = *q
}
```

---

As a side note, it is generally discouraged to use receiver names like `this` and `self`, instead the preferred way is to use a short, let's say 1 to 3 letters, abbreviation of the type's name.

For example:

```
func (r *Request) AddCookie(c *Cookie)
func (c *Client) Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @R3v4n answer:

1. Use chaining
2. Use [`db.Scopes`](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#scopes) for code reusage instead of usual func calls.

It can be like this:

```
query = shared.DB.Debug()
if query.Scopes(req.ApplyToDBQuery).find(&data).Error != nil {
  // handle error
}

func (this *MyCustomRequest) ApplyToDBQuery(query *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return query.Where(...).Limit(...).Offset(...)
}
```